# dd: "No space left" when restoring backup to exact same disk

Tags: backup, dd, restore

A while ago I made a backup of an entire disk using

`dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > backup.img.gz`

Today I restored this backup to the same disk using

`gunzip -c backup.img.gz | dd of=/dev/nvme0n1`

`dd` exited with the following error message:

```
dd: writing to '/dev/nvme0n1': No space left on device
1000215217+0 records in
1000215216+0 records out
512110190592 bytes (512 GB, 477 GiB) copied, 5769.06 s, 88.8 MB/s
```

Do I have to assume that the restore process failed?
If so, what can I do to restore my disk?

I also have a backup of `fdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1`, and now after the restore operation, the output of `fdisk -l` is the same like before, but I don't know if that is any guarantee of success.

Comment: Sparse files, perhaps?  (no, I guess that's not possible with a block device; forget I asked)

Comment: What does `gzip -l backup.img.gz` show as the uncompressed size?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, it shows 1009123328 as uncompressed and 22275182836 as compressed as well as a ratio of -2107.4% which seem to be wrong informations.

Comment: it's limited to 32bit number. 512110231552 % (2**32) = 1009123328. Even for smaller files you can not entirely trust this value, you have to unpack it and do a bytecount to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible for `dd conv=sync,noerror` (or `dd conv=noerror,sync`) [to corrupt data in some cases](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171).

However in your case it's probably simply surplus zeroes at the end of file. If your device is not exact multiple of 64K, your `dd` command would have filled the last 64K block with zeroes in the image file. And those additional zeroes can't be restored. Which would be harmless.

To verify that theory, you could run some commands:

```
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/nvme0n1
expected result: 512110190592
# gunzip < backup.img.gz | wc --bytes
expected result: 512110231552 (next multiple of 64K)
```

If that is correct then you're probably okay here.

Comment: `conv=sync` will pad a short read to a full block. Don't do it when reading from a compressed stream.

Comment: Your expected results are the exact numbers I get using the suggested commands. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen instances in which writing a compressed stream to `dd` can cause data to get lost. Try this

```
zcat backup.img.gz >/dev/nvme0n1
```

Or, if you must use `dd`, use this pipeline instead

```
gunzip -c backup.img.gz | dd iflag=fullblock bs=64K of=/dev/nvme0n1
```

If both of these fail then I would say that your replacement disk is smaller than the original.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep this commands in mind for future needs!